# Adding an event in device's calender in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have to set events in calendar. I used the reference https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-send-intent . 
I did installation and linking. and also manually set android folder files(setting/gradle, app/build.gradle and myApplication.java).
now in my component i wrote:

```
var SendIntentAndroid = require('react-native-send-intent');
SendIntentAndroid.addCalendarEvent({
    title: 'Go To The Park',
    description: "It's fun to play at the park.",
    startDate: '2016-01-25 10:00',
    endDate: '2016-01-25 11:00',
    recurrence: 'weekly',
    location: 'The Park'
});
```

this time i got the Error :

> "TypeError: TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...RNSendIntentAndroid.addCalendarEvent...')"

how can i solve it.please let me know if any other way in react-native to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

My all errors removed when i ejected expo from my project. now all is working fine.